# Prevent scrapy follow links of some web pages

Tags: python, scrapy

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector

from aibang.items import OrgItem

class OrgSpider(CrawlSpider):
  name = "org"
  allowed_domains = ["demo-site.com"]
  start_urls = [
      'http://demo-site.com/detail/17507640-419823665'
  ]

  rules = ( 
      # Item List
      Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(r'list\/\d+$', ))),
      # Parse item
      Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(r'detail\/\d+-\d+$', )), callback='parse_item', follow=False),
  )
  
  def parse_item(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

    item = OrgItem()
    try:
      item['name'] = hxs.select('//div[@class="b_title"]/h1/text()')[0].extract()
    except:
      print 'Something goes wrong, skip it'
    print item['name']
```

I'm using `Scrapy` to crawl some pages, but I don't want it follow the links in `detail/xxx-xxx` pages, how do I disable it ?

I have add `follow=False`, but it doesn't work, it still follow the links inside `detail/xxx-xxx`.

### ====== NOTE ======

I still need to crawl `detail page` from `list page`, but no more `detail page` inside another `detail page`.

Comment: try with a `deny` argument in your `SgmlLinkExtractor`. See http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html#sgmllinkextractor. But won't `deny=(r'detail/xxx-xxx',)` and `allow=(r'detail\/\d+-\d+$',)` clash?

Comment: Oh I misread. Simply try with `deny=(r'detail\/\d+-\d+$',)` alone, no `allow`, no `follow=False`

Comment: Hi, @paul, I still need to crawl the `detail page` from `list page` ? But no more `detail page` in side another `detail page`

Comment: I am new to scrapy. Maybe `DEPTH_LIMIT` in settings will help you

Comment: Seems I misread after all :) So you want to follow "list page" links, inside these "list pages" you want to follow "detail page" links, but in the "detail pages" you don't want to follow any links, right? What did not work with `follow=False` in the 2nd Rule? did it follow "list page" links? That's normal as per the first Rule (but duplicate links are normally filtered). I don't think you can restrict Rules from `rules` to certain callbacks (you could write something like that in your callback using LinkExtractors directly though)

Answer (score 0):

```
class scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml.SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(), deny=(), allow_domains=(), deny_domains=(), deny_extensions=None, restrict_xpaths=(), tags=('a', 'area'), attrs=('href'), canonicalize=True, unique=True, process_value=None)
```

> deny (a regular expression (or list of)) – a single regular expression
>   (or list of regular expressions) that the (absolute) urls must match
>   in order to be excluded (ie. not extracted). It has precedence over
>   the allow parameter. If not given (or empty) it won’t exclude any
>   links.

i hope it works for you

Comment: I don't understand, what will happened if I use it this way : `Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(r'detail\/\d+-\d+$', ), deny =(r'detail\/\d+-\d+$', ))), callback='parse_item', follow=False),`

Comment: follow=False , mean not even a single page would be followed , make it follow=True (its a default value i think) , and add the pages regex in deny that you don't want to crawl, or extract data from